# how to setup paypal adaptive payments with recurring billing feature

Tags: php, api, paypal, paypal-adaptive-payments, recurring-billing

are there any tutorials on how to setup paypal adaptive payments api with recurring billing?  I searched everywhere but only find the payflow and paypro with recurring billing.  And please don't link/point me to the dev docs on paypal's website, those don't really help since they are too detailed and long...and not to mention don't really show any code examples on this.

Comment: Do any of the suggestions on the sidebar help?

Comment: no because i need recurring payments with the paypal adaptive api.

Answer (score 3):

You could use the preapproval feature with Adaptive Payments to set up a type of recurring payment.  A preapproval is an approval to make future payments on the sender’s behalf.  So you could set your system up to automate the calls, such as a cron job or etc to process the payments for you.  There should be information on this in the Adaptive Payments guide.  Some online gaming sites use this features for purchases and subscriptions.